# java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out use getCause() to see the error chain

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

We are masking Sybase database using a third party tool written in Java. I am getting below error intermittently while masking a table of Sybase database. If I just re-execute the batch, it works fine so being really difficult to reproduce.

```
2020-01-09 04:41:55.657 Thread:Table Name - Error executing select statement for update 
2020-01-09 04:41:55.657 Error Executing Batch 
java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed 
out use getCause() to see the error chain
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:829)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseErrorCheckDead(ErrorMessage.java:1141)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:5186)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:5131)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:2921)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsCursor.fetch(TdsCursor.java:422)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsCursor.fetch(TdsCursor.java:351)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybCursorResultSet.next(SybCursorResultSet.java:187)
at com.grid_tools.products.datamasker.SQLUpdate.batchPreparedMasking(SQLUpdate.java:2706)
at com.grid_tools.products.datamasker.SQLUpdate.run(SQLUpdate.java:5717)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.timedio.RawDbio.reallyRead(RawDbio.java:322)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.timedio.Dbio.doRead(Dbio.java:253)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.timedio.InStreamMgr.readIfOwner(InStreamMgr.java:583)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.timedio.InStreamMgr.doRead(InStreamMgr.java:319)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsProtocolContext.getChunk(TdsProtocolContext.java:622)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.PduInputFormatter.readPacket(PduInputFormatter.java:239)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.PduInputFormatter.read(PduInputFormatter.java:72)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsInputStream.read(TdsInputStream.java:91)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsInputStream.readUnsignedByte(TdsInputStream.java:124)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:2879)
WHERE "row_id" = ?
```

Comment: _"java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"_, possibly the server hasn't sent data (yet) and your read timeout is configured too tight, or there is a problem with your network connection.

Comment: There are no issues with repect to network connection... How can I check the read time out values which is configured currently?

Comment: Check the Sybase JDBC documentation. I don't use Sybase myself, so I don't know the ins and outs of its JDBC driver.

Answer (score -3):

This is because of network issue at your end.. Probably your internet is not sable there.

Comment: I like it. I laughed.